# anchor or completion for logging events

Tags: react-native, branch.io

I'm using react native 0.61.5 with react-native-branch

I followed this tutorial as integration guide : https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/how-to-create-a-referall-system-using-branch-io-in-react-native-6f9f924149e0

is there a way when I use the branch.userCompletedAction() to get a completion or an anchor that the process has been done?

I need to fetch the credits as soon as the event has been logged.

this is my code :

```
export const logBranchEvent = async (
  eventName,
  eventParams,
  ) => {
  if (loggedToBranch) {
    await branch.userCompletedAction(eventName, eventParams);
    const res = await branch.loadRewards();
    console.log(res.credits)
   }
};
```

I get that there are 0 credits but when I wait and the check the credits I get the proper amount of credits.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a callback for branch.userCompletedAction() method. This method is used to log events.
You can try to fetch the rewards when the action is completed. It would not take more than 2 seconds. That would be best possible approach here.

Let me know if you would need further information here.